# How to Predict/Forecast street's Traffic based on previous values?

Tags: apache-spark, prediction

I have a dataset which has the following 5 columns:

```
date, hour, day_of_week, street_id, counts
```

My dataset has information about the number of cars that each street (same city) has in a given hour of a certain date, and I want to predict the traffic count that a certain street has in a given hour of a certain date.

I think I could use certain variables depending on the day and hour that I want to predict, for example, if a want to predict the traffic count of a working Wednesday:

1. Results of others working days
2. Results of others Wednesdays
3. ...

I want to use Spark MLlib to perform the prediction because I have experience with Spark and I have large datasets.

How you deal with this kind of problem?

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use `groupby()` for Wednesday and collect the results. Please check this [link](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2020/01/27/time-series-forecasting-prophet-spark.html).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `Time Series` problem. So based on a variable's past values, you try to predict the future values.

Usually an "unheard of" problem with Spark, but you are in luck ; [`spark-ts`](https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries) library seems to be doing what you need, so you don't need to code your own using MLlib. I recommend you try it out and then circle back to something in MLlib if things don't work.

They have introduced a [`TimeSeriesRDD`](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/spark-ts-a-new-library-for-analyzing-time-series-data-with-apache-spark/) and once you can encode your data in this data structure (Note that this still behaves like a normal `RDD`), you can play around with the models available. For example, implementing the `ARIMA` model would be as simple as  -

```
val arimaModel = ARIMA.fitModel(1, 0, 1, ts)
```

Hope that helps!